# Redux field not typing

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-redux

I'm stuck of this problem. I can't type anything in my input field. I use this `import {Field,reduxForm} from "redux-form";`
but fail again. This is just a simple field in redux. I already read this [link](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/GettingStarted.md/) about redux form. There is no special code and simple to apply but when I play it to my browser. I got that problem.

```
import * as React  from 'react';
import {Field,reduxForm} from "redux-form";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class TodoForm extends React.Component<any,any>{

    render(){
        return (
            <form>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                    <Field name="firstName" component="input" type="text"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
                    <Field name="lastName" component="input" type="text"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                    <Field name="email" component="input" type="email"/>
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

const TodoFormContainer = reduxForm({
    form: 'todo' // a unique name for this form
})(TodoForm);

export default connect()(TodoFormContainer);
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: "fail again" isn't a good error description. Please be more specific.

Comment: I did a lot of testing, even adding those import. actually, no error that display in my console, as in empty. that's my problem. I can't trace it.

Comment: Usually, when you can not type in your input field, that means that there is an `onChange` handler, but no update to the `value`. Why did you add `connect`? In your linked example this is not required.

Comment: Even If I remove the connect, still the problem occur. But I read the doc of redux form. There is no such thing onChange added on their example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue once. As I remember reason is that you didn't add formReducer in combineReducers() as shown below:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'

const reducers = {
  // ... your other reducers here ...
  form: formReducer     // <---- Mounted at 'form'
}
const reducer = combineReducers(reducers)
const store = createStore(reducer)
```